# I cannot create the same category name in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to make a category system according to years. For example
Iphone
Samsung
Xiaomi
Then I should assign years as subcategories to these categories.
2022
2021
2020

After all, there needs to be a structure like this.

```
Iphone/2020
Iphone/2021
Iphone/2022

Samsung/2020
Samsung/2021
Samsung/2022

Xiaomi/2020
Xiaomi/2021
Xiaomi/2022
```

In this table, the main categories are Iphone, Samsung and Xiaomi. When I want to open a subcategory for each main category, it creates a permalink problem. The problem I want to solve starts right here.

There is no problem with the first categories. The link structure is as follows.

```
example.com/iphone/2020
example.com/iphone/2021
example.com/iphone/2022
```

But when opening the 2nd and all other categories, the link structure is as follows;

```
example.com/samsung/2020-samsung
example.com/samsung/2021-samsung
example.com/samsung/2022-samsung
```

When I want to fix the permalink, I get an error like "the slug "2020" is already in use by another term".

There are many sites using this structure. However, I could not find how to do it. I think another structure is used for this process, not the wordpress category system. I would be very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is in the fact that wordpress manages the categories all together, therefore the "2020" category exists, because you have already created it, you should see if you can use it as a subcategory

Comment: I can't create subcategories anyway. The main categories are fixed and 1. So 2020,2021,2023, which I wrote here as categories, should actually be subcategories. Although these are subcategories connected to the main categories, when I create them anyway, there is a permalink problem.

Comment: I think you will need to change the reference slug and leave the name the same, this should work